# exporting and importing data between files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the collections variable stored in data.js in my App.js file. I've tried exporting and importing with the below code but it's not working. Anyone can tell me why?

---

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './data.js' in 'C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\sitecore\sitecore-test\sitecore\src'

---

**data.js**

```
const collections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        masterAssetId: 13,
        tags: {
            name: "Cartoon",
            subTag: {
                name: "Simpsons family",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2014",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Super heroes",
        masterAssetId: 24,
        tags: {
            name: "DC Super heroes",
            subTag: {
                name: "2014",
            },
        },
    }]

export {collections}
```

---

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Charles</h1>
      <h1>{collections[0].name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ["not working" isn't a useful description of the problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: It should work: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cartwright-5kq18?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './data.js' in 'C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\sitecore\sitecore-test\sitecore\src'

Comment: Your data.js should be exist in some other directory than App.js. Or not saved yet